# FilteringSelect paging using a JsonRest store in Dojo 1.7

Tags: dojo, paging, store

I'm trying to page results within a dijit.form.FilteringSelect that runs off a dojo.store.JsonRest store. The server receives the range header, parses it and returns the correct number of results accordingly, along with the Content-Range header in the format "items [start]-[end]/[total]". However, the range doesn't appear to be being used as if the pageSize is a factor of the  total number of results, the last page still shows the 'More Choices' option. A bit of investigation has shown that within dojo.store.JsonRest.query, the

```
results.total = results.then(function(){
    var range = results.ioArgs.xhr.getResponseHeader("Content-Range");
    return range && (range=range.match(/\/(.*)/)) && +range[1];
});
```

block appears to parse the Content-Range header correctly, however the returned value isn't being assigned to results.total, with it being assigned the Deferred object instead. Subsequently, results.total is not set to properly work with the following conditional in dijit.form._ComboBoxMenuMixin.createOptions:

```
// Try to determine if we should show 'more'...
if(results.total && !results.total.then && results.total != -1){
```

That condition fails, with results.total.then existing as a function stub, and the else is hit, resulting in the length of the results list being compared to the pageSize. Which means the results are paged properly until the last page is reached when it will show 'More Options' if exactly the same amount of results are returned as the pageSize.